# Using regex to redirect old domain to new while maintaining paths, but not redirecting if specific path in url exists

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, redirect

I am using Kinsta redirect tool to set a simple redirect from one domain to another. This needs to redirect for all paths, except for one specific path (no redirect should occur if it is present in URL). Example:

https://olddomain.com -> https://new.subdomain.com

https://olddomain.com/blog -> https://new.subdomain.com/blog

https://olddomain.com/faq -> https://new.subdomain.com/faq

However if:

https://olddomain.com/my-admin -> https://olddomain.com/my-admin (NO REDIRECT)

I basically need a single regex rule that can do this as I don't have access to a config file.

Closest thing I got was using (.*?.*/technology) to https://new.subdomain.com/$1 as a test; this resulted in only /technology page being redirected to new sites /technology page. I need the opposite behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can use the negative look ahead `(?!b)` syntax in regex which basically means "not matching `b`".

`^(?!\/?my-admin$)\/?(.*)$` to `https://new.example.com/$1`

- `^` - starts with
- `\/?` - Optional slash prefix
- `(?!\/?my-admin$)` - Not "my-admin" with an optional slash prefix
- `(.*)` - Any characters in caputuring group that becomes `$1`
- `$` ends with

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/1229

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for your response. So I attempted using this regex rule, however it still targeted /my-admin. It ended up redirecting to the new domains /my-admin path. The behavior I am seeking is that all paths redirect to new domain except for /my-admin, that specific path should maintain old domain.

Comment: If you look here https://regex101.com/r/jC8nB0/1229 it isn't it shouldn't match the my-admin URLs. Not all regex engines support negative look ahead.  Can you tell us more about the specific context this is used in?  What product is it?

Comment: So unfortunately were under NDA about specifics. However, a company is migrating its entire site to a new domain. There is a specific admin url path that allows access to dashboards. There is old data in the old dashboard that we need to access. Issue is when we hit /my-admin path on old domain to access old dashboard, it redirects to new domains /my-admin path making old impossible to reach. I ideally don't want to remove the redirect, and just tweak it to allow access to old domains /my-admin url path